# How to get changes to dataset and save changes to database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a program that reads data from database and displays it onto spreadsheetcontrol(devexpress).
I would like your help in enabling the program to get changes to the dataset on button_click, and then save it back into the database.
Thanks

here is a snippet of the code

```
        mentwall_DataDataSet ds = new mentwall_DataDataSet();
        mentwall_DataDataSetTableAdapters.DATABASETableAdapter databaseAdapter = new mentwall_DataDataSetTableAdapters.DATABASETableAdapter();
        databaseAdapter.Fill(ds.DATABASE);
        dv = new DataView(ds.DATABASE);

        mentwall_DataDataSet ds2 = new mentwall_DataDataSet();
        mentwall_DataDataSetTableAdapters.RegsTableAdapter regsAdapter = new mentwall_DataDataSetTableAdapters.RegsTableAdapter();
        regsAdapter.Fill(ds2.Regs);
        dv2 = new DataView(ds2.Regs);
```

This binds the data source

```
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[2];
        worksheet.DataBindings.BindToDataSource(dv, 1, 0);

        Worksheet worksheet2 = workbook.Worksheets[3];
        worksheet2.DataBindings.BindToDataSource(dv2, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done exactly the same, an application which shows content of a SQL table in a DevExpress Grid Control ( Windows Forms ) and when i click save button all changes ( including new rows added or deleted rows ) are persisted to the SQL Server database, here is a snippet of my DAL class which handles the database logic of saving:

the main point here is to use the SqlCommandBuilder class, which must be initialized with at least the select command and then all other commands are generated automatically, I have written this code > 5 years ago and i still use this app daily.

```
public int UpdateSQLDataTable(string connectionString, string TableName, DataTable dtSource)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sConn.Open();

            var transaction = sConn.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                var command = sConn.CreateCommand();
                command.Transaction = transaction;

                command.CommandText = $"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM {TableName} WITH (NOLOCK)";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                // timeoput of 5 minutes
                command.CommandTimeout = 300;

                SqlDataAdapter sAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

                SqlCommandBuilder sCMDB = new SqlCommandBuilder(sAdp);

                int affectedRecords = sAdp.Update(dtSource);

                transaction.Commit();

                return affectedRecords;
            }
            catch (Exception /* exp */)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Logger logger = new Logger();
        logger.Error(string.Format("connectionString: '{0}', TableName: '{1}'", connectionString, TableName), exc);

        return int.MinValue;
    }
}
```